# How to restream m3u8 with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I use nginx rtmp and followig command:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -hide_banner -i https://ch.iptvmate.net/ec6e5689ffd6f9690102640bddd2f9e7.m3u8 -c copy -f hls -hls_time 4 -hls_flags append_list+delete_segments -hls_list_size 6 -hls_segment_filename 'hls/ch2/file%03d.ts' hls/ch2/playlist.m3u8
```

It streams but not live, it has recorded one period of the channel and this link streams this period again and again. Is the command correct? I just created the folder called ch2 and it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to push stream as rtmp, HLS parameters are not required.

Simple way to re-stream via rtmp into nginx:

```
ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -hide_banner -i https://ch.iptvmate.net/ec6e5689ffd6f9690102640bddd2f9e7.m3u8 -c copy -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/live/stream
```

Afterwards, you can configure your live block in Nginx to have HLS.

```
        application live {
        live on;
        hls on;
        hls_path /tmp/hls;
    }
```

Eventually, you would like to have chunks over HTTP:

```
        location /hls {
        # Serve HLS fragments
        types {
            application/vnd.apple.mpegurl m3u8;
            video/mp2t ts;
        }
        root /tmp;
        add_header Cache-Control no-cache;
    }
```

Try http://127.0.0.1/hls/stream.m3u8 when configuration is successful and ffmpeg is running.